# Deleting a row with mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-delete

I am trying to delete a record of `richiestePreventivo` but when I do this Sql code in phpmyadmin I have 0 rows deleted:

```
DELETE FROM `RichiestePreventivo` as `p` WHERE (`p`.`idImpresa` = 17)
```

In `richiestePreventivo` I have one record containing:

```
id  idPrivato   idImpresa   data_invio
13  11          17          2011-08-25
```

[image: my database]

What is the problem?

Comment: Try `DELETE FROM RichiestePreventivo WHERE idImpresa = 11`

Comment: Did you try it without aliasing the table?  I'm not sure why you would need to do that (although I wouldn't think that was the problem...). `DELETE FROM RichiestePreventivo WHERE idImpresa = 11`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May be this column is a foreign key to another table and the foreign key properties for ON DELETE doesnot have a CASCADE option but has a NO ACTION option

Comment: What management tool are you using ? Toad ? Mysql Workbench ?

Comment: Or use the following syntax, ALTER TABLE tbl_name ADD [CONSTRAINT [symbol]] FOREIGN KEY [index_name] (index_col_name, ...) REFERENCES tbl_name (index_col_name,...) [ON DELETE reference_option] [ON UPDATE reference_option] change the reference_option to CASCADE and by the way you have to DROP and create the constraint or ALTER the constraint

Comment: -1 Wouldn't that throw an error? I think this is not OPs problem

Comment: ALTER TABLE `gestionepreventivi`.`richiestepreventivo` 
  ADD CONSTRAINT `1 impresa piu richieste preventivo`
  FOREIGN KEY (`idImpresa` )
  REFERENCES `gestionepreventivi`.`imprese` (`id` )
  ON DELETE CASCADE;
So with this, if I delete a row on imprese, will be deleted also records on richiestePreventivi where idImpresa==richiestepreventivo.id ????

Answer (score 1):

As long as the PK of richiestePreventivo table is not a foreign key of some other table you can:

```
DELETE FROM RichiestePreventivo WHERE (idImpresa = 17)
```

or

I know this works in SQL Server but not sure if it works in DB that you are using

```
DELETE p FROM RichiestePreventivo as p WHERE (p.idImpresa = 17)
```

The second statement is very useful when you have to join multiple tables and using aliases.

Answer (score 0):

try putting values in quotes like this:

```
DELETE FROM RichiestePreventivo as p WHERE (p.idImpresa = "11")
```

Comment: I don't think that would do it, since he shows in the schema that the idImpresa field is an Int